# Supabase auth in Flutter Desktop

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-flutter

I am writing a multi-platform Flutter **desktop** app (macOS, Windows, Linux) and am trying to get Supbase Auth to work.
I can present a `SupaMagicAuth` widget, but for the app to know anything about the magic link having been clicked I need to launch the app *from* the magic-link, which means I need to associate the app with my callback URL scheme. In the past, I've done this on iOS and Android with other auth providers, never in a Flutter desktop app.

Does anyone know:

1. If there are any instructions on how to associate a redirect URL with the project in the types of native wrappers that Flutter creates?
2. If there the Supabase SDK has something where I can send a OTP to the user's email, then have them enter the code they received manually to create an auth session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, supabase_flutter has deep link support. You can find some descriptions and links to the instruction on the README.md file of supabase_flutter.
https://pub.dev/packages/supabase_flutter#deep-links

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find any documentation in the docs on Supabase Auth. 
Looks like Supabase has a dependency on the `app_links` package (which does have instructions on deep-linking in Flutter).   
https://pub.dev/packages/app_links